# .Net Directory services for local authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directoryservices

I am using directory services in .Net for first time.I want to use it to authenticate against local users on my machine in an asp.net website application
The code is as follows

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://"+Environment.MachineName+"/administrator", txtBoxUserName.Text, txtBoxPWD.Text);
```

For some reason I get an exception of "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" although I used the right user name and password for administrator user.

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public bool IsAuthenticationValid(string userName, string password)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
    }
}
```

Edit: Forgot to mention you will need System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement references.

If you hit the same error, please describe what environment you are running this code in. By that I mean command line, web app, etc. Just some more background to see if I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks..If the user does not exist it returns true.If user exists and if password is wrong it returns false.So had to use UserPrincipal.findbyIndentity() to check whether user actually exists

Comment: @Krishnanunni Jeevan it doesn't do that for me. If the user doesn't exist or the password is incorrect I get a false response, otherwise true. Interesting :)

Comment: I think it is there only in windows Xp and if guest accounts are enabled